# Access Property of Generic without common base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have two independent classes of a library which doesn't have the same base class, neither I can change the implementation of this classes.

Imagine the classes look like this:

```
public class A {
     public int X { get; } = 1;
}

public class B {
     public int X { get; } = 2;
}
```

Now I want to create a generic class, which is either depending on `A` or on `B` and access the value of `X` in there.

So i did:

```
public class GenericClass<T> 
    /*where T : ?*/
{
    void Foo(T t) {
        int x = t.X; // is this possible and how? 
    }
}
```

If I would implement `A` and `B` on myself, I would define an Interface which implements the Property `X`, but I can't do this. Is there any other way, without changing class `A` and `B`, to say that the Generic `T` has the Property `X`?
Another idea would be to make child classes of `A` and `B` which then implement the mentioned Interface, but I want to avoid this.

Comment: [I found this Dev article that might help](https://dev.to/fluffynuts/duck-typing-with-peanutbutter-4j54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `dynamic`.

```
dynamic d;
d = t;         // here t can be an instance of A, or or B, or of anything that has X
int x = d.X;
```

`dynamic` essentially implements "duck typing": if a `dynamic` object `g` has a property `X`, then `g.X` will retrieve it. This is an alternative to implementing reflection manually.

Comment: What happens, if X isn't implemented?

Comment: It will still compile correctly, but cause a run-time exception: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 't' does not contain a definition for 'X'`.

Comment: I will make your answer the correct one, because it "solves" my problem. I know it isn't a good solution, because of the dangers of exceptions and so on

Comment: Well, one has to guard and catch such exceptions, and handle them appropriately. Also note that `dynamic` is generally considered rather slow, but it has its uses.

Answer (score 5):

You can overload `Foo` to take either `A` or `B`:

```
void Foo(A t)
{
  int x = t.X;
}

void Foo(B t)
{
  int x = t.X;
}
```

If you want to do it for every conceivable class that might have an `X` property then you'll need a reflection based solution. For example:

```
void Foo(object obj)
{
  var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("X");
  if(property == null) throw new Exception();

  int x = (int)property.GetValue(obj);
}
```

NOTE: I've minimized the error handling here. You'd need to handle the case where the property might not have a getter (rare) or where it doesn't return an `int`

If the number of classes is manageable then you could create an interface with the property, derive a new class and implement the interface, which won't require a change. For example:

```
interface IMyStuff
{
  int X{get;}
}

class MyA : A, IMyStuff
{
}

class MyB : B, IMyStuff
{
}
```

Not you can have Foo accept the interface:

```
void Foo(IMyStuff stuff)
{
  int x = stuff.X
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post virtually the same answer :-) +1.

Comment: But I would have to do this for every class possible. Foo stays the same for every class I can pass (right now). And my example was bad. I create an instance of the template sometimes, too

Comment: @RoQuOTriX _"But I would have to do this for every class possible."_ That is the consequence of explicitly restricting the problem to one where you don't setup any shared ancestry between the two(or more) classes. In order to be reusable, you need to define what these classes have in common.

Comment: @Flater I agree with you, but it would be nice if I could say that a generic has to have common Properties e.g. in my where statement, which I usually would do with an interface, but sometimes I can't. Now I either have to subclass every class of my library and make a common base class or use reflection based solution for such an "easy" problem

Comment: @RoQuOTriX - I've updated the answer to show a third option.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: The premise (not changing the existing classes) will always lead to some extra (and less ideal) effort from your side. You _could_ wrap the classes though. That at least allows you to contain the problem to the existing library and have a cleaner solution in your code.

Comment: @Sean: In regards to the third option, I'd generally advocate composition over inheritance here. But from a technical perspective, either would work :)